# Eclipse plugin: How to secure sensitive data?

Tags: java, eclipse, security, plugins, sensitive-data

I'm currently building an Eclipse plugin which creates and stores sensitive data, let's say "highscores".

As users can simply unpack the jar file, they are able to see the source code of the project. Thus they are able to cheat and create a faked highscore file by either changing the data in the file itself or writing to the highscore file (as they know how the data is encrypted from the source code).

Can I encrypt my jar file so that users cannot read the source code, but the plugin is still working properly?

Comment: Jar files don't normally contain the source code, just the .class files.

Comment: So its not possible to "decompile" the bytecode? Does that mean that I can use an encryption method of my choice inside the plugin for creating and encrypting the highscore list without any security issues?

Comment: There are tools to decompile the class files. there are also tools like Proguard to make the decompiled code hard to read. If your code runs on the user's machine it can be hacked one way or another all you can is make it difficult.

Answer (score 1):

As greg-449 already commented, that when the code is with user, it can be hacked in one way or the another. If Encryption of secure data is not going to help, you can move the secure data on your server.

Impact would be, it is available only when the user is online.

Another solution, a bit complex one:

Don't store High Score at all. Store/ log the user's activities to calculate high score. make the logs encrypted to add more security. Use salt, timestamp and secure key while encryption and a checksum to prevent manual changes to the file.

Comment: Isn't storing the logs the same as storing the highscore file?

Comment: yes, it is similar. What I meant is instead of keeping scores at single location, derive raw material from different locations and then construct. However, this does not solves our problem completely,it increases problems for the hacker.